FoxId code cannot be authorized (missing client id)
I am trying to authenticate a user to FoxId through a OpenId Connect Application. I am able to generate a code when I have logged into the application I have created. When the redirect happens I am receiving a code provided by FoxId. However when I try to authorize the code, I get the following error message: Invalid client id ''.
I have verified my clientId and clientsecret is the same as on the application I have created, but I still receive that error.
My code looks like the following:
public class FoxIdService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory, string clientId, string clientSecret) : ITokenService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient = clientFactory.CreateClient("FoxIdClient");

    public string GetAuthorizationUrlAsync()
    {
        // Create the authorization request URL
        var requestUrl = new RequestUrl($"https://foxids.com/company-test/test/{clientId}/oauth/authorize");
        var authorizationUrl = requestUrl.CreateAuthorizeUrl(
            clientId: clientId,
            responseType: "code",
            redirectUri: "https://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/callback",
            scope: "openid"
        );

        return authorizationUrl;
    }


    public async Task<string?> GetCallBackToken(string code)
    {
        var tokenEndpoint = $"https://foxids.com/company-test/test/{clientId}/oauth/token";
        
        var tokenRequest = new AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest
        {
            Address = tokenEndpoint,
            ClientId = clientId,
            ClientSecret = clientSecret,
            Code = code,
            RedirectUri = "https://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/callback"
        };

        var response = await _httpClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeTokenAsync(tokenRequest);
        return response.AccessToken;
    }
}

I have tried many different approaches to making this work where I have disabled several settings in the FoxId application UI, where I have disabled PKCE and added all response types from FoxId but to no success.
If anyone could help me, that would be greatly appreciated.

FoxIDs default expect the client ID and client secret as part of the HTTP post body, where the IdentityModel code default send the client ID and client secret as a HTTP authorization header.
You can change the configured application in FoxIDs to use HTTP authorization header, like this.

Navigate to the Applications tab and select your application
Click the Advanced options in the top right corner of your application configuration
In Client authentication method select Client secret basic


You can also alternatively select to uses a X509 certificate as client secret with Private key JWT.
A side node
The URLs do not include a authentication method(s) selection for the application. It is recommended to explicitly select the configured authentication method(s), e.g. with (*) to select all configured authentication methods. If not selected, FoxIDs defaults to select all configured authentication methods.
Selecting all authentication methods:
https://foxids.com/test-corp/-/aspnet_oidc_allup_sample(*)/.well-known/openid-configuration
The authorization and token endpoints then include the selector (*).
Not selecting authentication method:
https://foxids.com/test-corp/-/aspnet_oidc_allup_sample/.well-known/openid-configuration
The authorization and token endpoints is then without the selector (*).
-------- EDIT --------
From FoxIDs version 1.6.17
If the client authentication post method is configured and a client secret is not received. FoxIDs default use the client authentication basic method instead.
